# How do I create both a .lib file and an .exe file in Visual C++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, linker, static-libraries

I currently have a console project which creates an .exe file; I want it to also create a .lib file so other projects, compiled as DLLs, would be able to call functions from the original project.

I know it is possible, but I couldn't find how to do that. How do I tell the linker to also link a .lib?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Posting this just as a reference I know the original post was posted long time ago but this still applies to anyone who needs a solution to this problem.

Go to the project you want to make a .lib file for and follow these steps:

1. Right click on the project.
2. Select Properties.
3. Select Build Events.
4. Select Pre-Link Event .
5. Finally in the Command Line paste this:

   `@ECHO ON
   @ECHO "$(VC_ExecutablePath_x86)\lib.exe" /out:"$(OutDir)$(ProjectName).lib" "$(IntermediateOutputPath)*.obj"
   "$(VC_ExecutablePath_x86)\lib.exe" /out:"$(OutDir)$(ProjectName).lib" "$(IntermediateOutputPath)*.obj"`

This will call the lib tool to generate the lib file out of the generated object files.

Comment: Kind of late, but wanted to thank you anyway :) You just made my life a whole lot easier

Comment: In my case the default localtion for .obj was in the project folder, so i changed "$(IntermediateOutputPath)*.obj"  to "$(SolutionDir)$(ProjectName)\$(Configuration)\*.obj". it works fine, thanks.

Comment: Excellent option, better late than never. Thanks !

Answer (score 10):

It's not possible in general - static libraries and executables are completely different kinds of animal. The way to handle this situation is to create two projects - one for the library, which contains all the functionality. and one for the executable, which is a thin wrapper that simply calls functions in the library.

Comment: But right here I have a vcproj file that DOES end up with both an exe and a lib... Yet for the life of me I couldn't find what made it do that.

http://svn.corecraft.org/aspire_mirror/trunk/win/VC90/hearthstone-world.vcproj

Comment: @Spidey Presumably the project contains two sub-projects.

Comment: agreed. Make the exe project depend on the lib project and it'll get automatically recompiled when needed.

Comment: I see, one of the projects in the solution was actually a static library which the other used, just like you've suggested. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 7):

If any symbol in a Application (.exe) project is exported (e.g. with __declspec(dllexport) ), both the .exe and the .lib files will be generated 
See:
[Why does my Visual C++ .exe project build create .lib and .exp files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2820694/why-does-my-visual-c-exe-project-build-create-lib-and-exp-files)

Comment: This is correct w.r.t. the question in the title. However, how would this help with the other question in the body; "be able to call functions from the original [EXE] project"?

Comment: You link against the generated .lib; the .exe behaves as a DLL. i.e. the symbols are loaded at runtime from the .exe.

Comment: I tested what I wrote in the last comment. It sometimes work and sometimes don't with, a "Cannot initialize application (0xC0000005)" error. Using LoadLibrary and GetProcAddress I also end up with memory problems. So actually I do not know how to use the generated .lib properly.

Answer (score 1):

It is amazing how many contributors arrogantly insists on an answer that is wrong, when *they* simply don't know the answer.

To generate a .lib associated with your .exe place the following line in Pre-Link Event:

```
"$(VC_ExecutablePath_x86)\lib.exe" /out:"$(OutDir)$(ProjectName).lib" "$(IntermediateOutputPath)*.obj"
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't "also link a lib", you create a static library project. The latter doesn't call the linker at all -- instead it compiles all your files with `cl /c` and combines the resulting `.obj`s into a lib using `lib.exe`.