# Visual Studio 2010 C++ Project: Build Release EXE File generates EXE, LIB and EXP File. Why?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, release, exe, exp

I'm building a C++ project in Release-Mode and the target type is an EXE-File. The project also generates a .lib and a .exp-file. What is wrong? I only want to build an exe-file.

Any ideas?

Thank you very much!!!

Comment: You are linking code that contains a declaration that has the `__declspec(dllexport)` attribute.  That code was meant to go in a DLL, you linked it into a EXE instead.

Comment: Yes...i found the solution on Stackoverflow while searching with other  keywords. Thank you for your help. Have a nice day!

BTW...here's the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2820694/why-does-my-visual-c-exe-project-build-create-lib-and-exp-files

Comment: well, I cant find __declspec(dllexport) in my project, for sure I didnt wrote it myself, searching the entire solution for this also results in noting..so Im not really understanding if this is normal or my project have a bug in its configuration files