# Visual Studio (2013) Unit Test fails with C0000005

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unit-testing

I just set up a new (native) unit test in a new Solution. But even the example program does not work if I add an Assertion. It compiles without problems and the default generated (empty) test succeeds. But when I add a simple Assertion it fails with error code C0000005.

This is probably related to a [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18168520/unit-tests-fail-with-exception-code-c0000005), but I don't even have some library connected and therefore can't use the proposed solutions.

The test looks like this:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "CppUnitTest.h"

using namespace Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework;

namespace Test_Native
{       
TEST_CLASS(UnitTest1)
{
public:

    TEST_METHOD(TestMethod1)
    {
        Assert::AreEqual(1, 1, L"message", LINE_INFO());  // Without this line everything is fine
        // TODO: Your test code here
    }

};
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a [known bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/804696/linking-visual-studio-2012-c-unit-testing-project-against-an-exe-causes-access-violations). Unfortunately, Microsoft considers this as "Won't Fix".

In short, there are two workarounds:

Compile the actual project in release mode and the test project in debug mode.
Outsource all testable functions to a static library project.